# Loop Command (discord.py)

Tags: python, bots, discord

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def repeat(ctx):

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice.is_playing:
            return await ctx.send('Aucune musique joué !')

    await ctx.send("La répétition est activé \n Si vous voulez désactivé : n#stop")

    voice.loop = True
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

Why is it not repeating the music I play with my **play** command endlessly?

Answer (score 0):

hey why don't you try itertools. Im not really an expert with music bots so ill use ctx.send() for now.

```
from itertools import cycle
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@commands.command()
async def repeat():
    music_list = cycle(["song1","song2"])
    while True:
        time.sleep("length of song")
        await ctx.send(next(music_list))
```

cycle is a really nice way of looping and you should really try it
this is an example of how cycle works and maybe this tut might help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RK8RzuUMYt8

Comment: Just trying to help